# how to completely remove

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

please help to remove the new Bullet. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xVcr/1/)

after the object it moves across the screen from the bottom up. coordinate with y <= 5px method works helper.deleteElement (), but the object is still there exists (see the console - console.log ('move') ;)

I need to to be removed completely

js:

```
Bullet = function(bulletId){ 
    var self = this;

    self.id = bulletId; 
    self.x = 100;   
    self.y = 500;   

    self.move = function(){ 
        console.log('move');

        var offsetY = -10,
            newY = self.y + offsetY;

        if(newY <= 5){
            helper.deleteElement(self.id);

            if(observerable.removeListener(this, "makeMoveBullet", "move")){
                console.log('dont worked!');
            }
        }   

        self.y = newY;

        self.render(self.x, newY);      

        return;
    };      

    self.render = function(x, y){       
        $('#' +self.id).css({
            'left': (self.x = x || self.x) + 'px',
            'top': (self.y = y || self.y) + 'px'
        }).appendTo('#wrap');   

        return;
    };

    self.init = function(playerX, playerY){
        $('<div class="bullet" id="' + self.id + '"  />').appendTo('#wrap');

        self.x = playerX + 31;
        self.y = playerY - 9;

        self.render(self.x, self.y);

        return;
    };
}; 


// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ observer
var observerable = {
    listeners: {},

    addListener: function (object, evt, callback) {       
        if (!this.listeners.hasOwnProperty(evt)) {           
            this.listeners[evt] = [];    
        }        

        this.listeners[evt].push(object[callback]);       
    },

    removeListener: function (object, evt, callback) {       
        if (this.listeners.hasOwnProperty(evt)) {      
            var i, length;     
                    
            for (i = 0, length = this.listeners[evt].length; i < length; i += 1) {               
                if (this.listeners[evt][i] === object[callback]) {                   
                    this.listeners[evt].splice(i, 1);        
                }      
            }    
        }  
    },
        
    publisher: function (evt, args) {       
        if (this.listeners.hasOwnProperty(evt)){                       
            var i, length;       
                                      
            for (i = 0, length = this.listeners[evt].length; i < length; i += 1){                
                this.listeners[evt][i](args);      
            }            
        }                            
    }
}; 

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ helper
function Helper(){
    this.deleteElement = function(id){
        $('#' + id).remove();

        return;
    };  
};

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ init
var helper = new Helper();


bullet = new Bullet('bullet_0'); 

bullet.init(500, 500);


observerable.addListener(bullet, "makeMoveBullet", "move"); 

setInterval(function(){
    observerable.publisher("makeMoveBullet");
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript uses a Garbage Collector to remove unused variables. I would say to do something like this:

```
delete this.x; delete this.y ; ... ; delete this;
```

When you want to remove the object (also remove it from any other external data structures). Remove all it's properties then the object itself. Then the GC should remove it.

Comment: thanks for the information. but as long as there is at least one link, the garbage collector does not destroy the object. a link exists in the design-pattern observer.

that is, in my stake method fails observerable.removeListener (this, "makeMoveBullet", "move")

http://jsfiddle.net/9xVcr/3/

Comment: Remove the bullet directly since it was added directly: http://jsfiddle.net/9xVcr/5/

Answer (score 0):

setInterval returns an interval identifier. Clear the interval using clearInterval function when you don't want more executions of the interval.

```
var int = setInterval(...);
...
clearInterval(int);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
removeListener: function (object, evt, callback) {
    if (this.listeners.hasOwnProperty(evt)) {
        var i, length;

        for (i = 0, length = this.listeners[evt].length; i < length; i += 1) {
            if (this.listeners[evt][i] === object[callback]) {
                this.listeners[evt].splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`object[callback]` is always undefined so `this.listeners[evt].splice(i, 1);` cannot be executed;